network optimisation supply planning is not generating weekly plan
I am working on Production planning optimization where I have three stages of planning

Production plan
Packaging plan
Dispatch plan
for each stage I have its capacity and lead time it takes for each stage.
I have my demand on each state level

I am developing my code in glpk optimizer with PYOMO library to solve linear problem the model shows that i have found optimal solution but for some reason it is not generating any non zero value
here is my sample dictionary data

Demand: 
financial: 
dispatch_lt:

packaging_LT:

dispatch_capacity:

packaging capacity:

production capacity:

config Yaml file:
n_days_optimise: 7
factories: ['Factory_1']
products: ['P1']
pack_sizes: ['10 L']
states: ['mah']
depots: ['d1']
varient: ['v1']


#Model parameter
solver: 'glpk' # glpk,Gurobi,CEPLEX
model_time_limit: 5400  # Default
model_gap_rel: 0.05  # Default

here are the business constraints i wrote for this
def get_all_params(data,config):
    # print(data)
    demand=data["Demand"]
    financial=data["Financial"]
    mkt_inv=data["Market_inventory"]
    dispatch_lt=data["Dispatch_LT"]
    packaging_lt=data["Packaging_LT"]
    production_lt=data["Production_LT"]
    dispatch_cap=data["Dispatch_capacity"]
    packaging_capacity=data["Packaging_capacity"]
    production_capacity=data["Production_capacity"]


    return demand,financial,mkt_inv,dispatch_lt,packaging_lt,production_lt,dispatch_cap,packaging_capacity,production_capacity

def model_optimizer(data,config):
    print(data)
    n_days=range(1,config['n_days_optimise']+1)
    # Initialize the model 
    model=pyo.ConcreteModel()
    # Sets
    model.factories=pyo.Set(initialize=config["factories"])
    model.products=pyo.Set(initialize=config["products"])
    model.pack_size=pyo.Set(initialize=config["pack_sizes"])
    model.states=pyo.Set(initialize=config["states"])
    model.depots=pyo.Set(initialize=config["depots"])
    model.varients=pyo.Set(initialize=config["varient"])
    model.days=pyo.RangeSet(config["n_days_optimise"])

    # parameter extraction 
    demand,financial,mkt_inv,dispatch_lt,packaging_lt,production_lt,dispatch_cap,packaging_capacity,production_capacity=get_all_params(data,config)

    #decision variables
    model.production=pyo.Var(model.factories,model.products,model.days,within=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
    model.packaging = pyo.Var(model.factories, model.varients,model.pack_size,model.days, within=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
    model.dispatch = pyo.Var(model.factories, model.varients,model.pack_size, model.depots, model.states, model.days, within=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
    model.sales = pyo.Var(model.varients, model.states, model.depots, model.pack_size, model.days, within=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
    model.market_inventory = pyo.Var(model.varients, model.states, model.depots, model.pack_size, model.days, within=pyo.NonNegativeReals)

    # gross_margin = {(row['state'], row['Depot'], row['Product'], row['varient'], row['pack size'], row['Factory']): row['Gross Margin'] for index, row in financial.iterrows()}
    gross_margin=financial

    # Objective function
    def objective_rule(model):

        return sum(
            model.dispatch[f, v, ps, depot, state, d] * gross_margin.get((state, depot, p, v, ps, f), 0)
            for f in model.factories
            for p in model.products
            for v in model.varients
            for ps in model.pack_size
            for depot in model.depots
            for state in model.states
            for d in model.days
        )
    
    model.objective = pyo.Objective(rule=objective_rule, sense=pyo.maximize)


    #constraints

    # Demand constraint (sales must not exceed demand)
    def sales_demand_constraint_rule(model, v, s, depot, ps, d):
        return model.sales[v, s, depot, ps, d] <= demand.get((depot, s, v, ps, d), 0)
    model.sales_demand_constraint = pyo.Constraint(model.varients, model.states, model.depots, model.pack_size, model.days, rule=sales_demand_constraint_rule)

    # capacity Constraints
    # Production capacity constraint
    def production_capacity_rule(model, f, d):
        return sum(model.production[f, p, d] for p in model.products) <= production_capacity.get((f, d), 0)
    model.production_capacity_constraint = pyo.Constraint(model.factories, model.days, rule=production_capacity_rule)

    # Packaging capacity constraint
    def packaging_capacity_rule(model, f, d):
        return sum(model.packaging[f, v, ps, d] for v in model.varients for ps in model.pack_size) <= packaging_capacity.get((f, d), 0)
    model.packaging_capacity_constraint = pyo.Constraint(model.factories, model.days, rule=packaging_capacity_rule)

    # Dispatch capacity constraint
    def dispatch_capacity_rule(model, f, ps, d):
        return sum(model.dispatch[f, v, ps, depot, state, d] for v in model.varients for depot in model.depots for state in model.states) <= dispatch_cap.get((f, ps), 0)
    model.dispatch_capacity_constraint = pyo.Constraint(model.factories, model.pack_size, model.days, rule=dispatch_capacity_rule)


    # lead time constraints 
    def lead_time_production_rule(model, f, p, d):
        lead_time = production_lt.get((f, p), 0)
        if lead_time > 0 and d > lead_time:
        # Constraint to ensure the production respects the lead time
            return model.production[f, p, d] <= sum(model.production[f, p, d - i] for i in range(1, lead_time + 1))
        elif lead_time == 0:
        # If lead time is zero, production can occur without delay
            return model.production[f, p, d] <= production_capacity.get((f, d), 0)
        else:
            return pyo.Constraint.Skip

    model.lead_time_production_constraint = pyo.Constraint(model.factories, model.products, model.days, rule=lead_time_production_rule)


    def lead_time_packaging_rule(model, f, v, ps, d):
        lead_time = packaging_lt.get((f, ps), 0)
        if d > lead_time:
            return model.packaging[f, v, ps, d] <= model.packaging[f, v, ps, d - lead_time]
        else:
            return pyo.Constraint.Skip
    model.lead_time_packaging_constraint = pyo.Constraint(model.factories, model.varients, model.pack_size, model.days, rule=lead_time_packaging_rule)



    def lead_time_dispatch_rule(model, f, v, ps, depot, state, d):
        lead_time = dispatch_lt.get((f, state), 0)
        if d > lead_time:
            return model.dispatch[f, v, ps, depot, state, d] <= model.dispatch[f, v, ps, depot, state, d - lead_time]
        else:
            return pyo.Constraint.Skip
    model.lead_time_dispatch_constraint = pyo.Constraint(model.factories, model.varients, model.pack_size, model.depots, model.states, model.days, rule=lead_time_dispatch_rule)


    def demand_fulfillment_constraint_rule(model, p, ps, depot, state, d):
    # Calculate the total demand for the product in the specified state, depot, and pack size
        total_demand = sum(demand.get((depot, state, p, v, ps), 0) for v in model.varients)
    
    # Ensure that the sum of production, packaging, and dispatch equals or exceeds the demand
        return (
        sum(model.production[f, p, d] for f in model.factories) +
        sum(model.packaging[f, v, ps, d] for f in model.factories for v in model.varients) +
        sum(model.dispatch[f, v, ps, depot, state, d] for f in model.factories for v in model.varients)
    ) >= total_demand

# Add demand fulfillment constraints to the model
    model.demand_fulfillment_constraint = pyo.Constraint(model.products, model.pack_size, model.depots, model.states, model.days, rule=demand_fulfillment_constraint_rule)

    
    # Solve the model
    solver = pyo.SolverFactory('glpk')
    result= solver.solve(model,tee=True)

    if (result.solver.status == pyo.SolverStatus.ok) and (result.solver.termination_condition == pyo.TerminationCondition.optimal):
        print('Solution is optimal')
    elif result.solver.termination_condition == pyo.TerminationCondition.infeasible:
        print('Solution is infeasible')
    else:
        print('Solver Status: ', result.solver.status)


I have tried changing my optimizer objective function to
 def objective_rule(model):

        return (
        sum(model.production[f, p, d] for f in model.factories for p in model.products for d in model.days) +
        sum(model.packaging[f, v, ps, d] for f in model.factories for v in model.varients for ps in model.pack_size for d in model.days) +
        sum(model.dispatch[f, v, ps, depot, state, d] for f in model.factories for v in model.varients for ps in model.pack_size for depot in model.depots for state in model.states for d in model.days)
    )

    model.objective = pyo.Objective(rule=objective_rule, sense=pyo.maximize)

here is the output extraction stage:
n_days = len(model.days)
    production_plan = {(f, p, d): pyo.value(model.production[f, p, d]) 
                       for f in model.factories for p in model.products 
                       for d in model.days}

    packaging_plan = {(f, v, ps, d): pyo.value(model.packaging[f, v, ps, d]) 
                      for f in model.factories for v in model.varients 
                      for ps in model.pack_size for d in model.days}

    dispatch_plan = {(f, v, ps, depot, state, d): pyo.value(model.dispatch[f, v, ps, depot, state, d]) 
                     for f in model.factories for v in model.varients 
                     for ps in model.pack_size for depot in model.depots 
                     for state in model.states for d in model.days}

attaching my log:
GLPSOL: GLPK LP/MIP Solver, v4.65
Parameter(s) specified in the command line:
 --write C:\Users\PRASHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpcer9wsbf.glpk.raw --wglp
 C:\Users\PRASHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpj_7dgkpm.glpk.glp --cpxlp C:\Users\PRASHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpy9lm30pg.pyomo.lp
Reading problem data from 'C:\Users\PRASHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpy9lm30pg.pyomo.lp'...
56 rows, 29 columns, 56 non-zeros
297 lines were read
Writing problem data to 'C:\Users\PRASHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpj_7dgkpm.glpk.glp'...
222 lines were written
GLPK Simplex Optimizer, v4.65
56 rows, 29 columns, 56 non-zeros
Preprocessing...
~     0: obj =   0.000000000e+00  infeas =  0.000e+00
OPTIMAL SOLUTION FOUND BY LP PREPROCESSOR
Time used:   0.0 secs
Memory used: 0.0 Mb (48420 bytes)
Writing basic solution to 'C:\Users\PRASHA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpcer9wsbf.glpk.raw'...
94 lines were written
Solution is optimal
model executed

I have also played with the Input value. checked the data is getting parsed but for some reason, the decision variable is not able to generate any non-zero value. Any feedback or approach change would be appreciated.

I would suggest chopping down your dataset to something very small (just a couple items) that you can solve by hand and testing your model with that and using model.pprint() to inspect the constraints.  I'm betting that "0" is correct because one of your constraints is binding or maybe incorrectly written and it will show up much easier with a small test case

Thanks for replying @AirSquid. You are correct all the values are showing "0". I put a single line item data as well. From Var Declaration Lower and value is 0. demand fulfillment constraint lower is zero. all other constraint Lower is -Inf and upper is zero. I might require little help in understanding what constraint or objective function is causing an issue.

Your problem is not reproducible.  If you're looking for help it troubleshooting, your example should be fully self-contained and copy-paste reproducible to someone who can help.  Your data is unusable and get_params() is missing.  You can edit your question to make it reproducible.

I "suspect" that get_params() may be doing something weird and when you are using the get(..., 0) in all of your constraints, you are pulling up zeros.  Test them

I created get_params() function for future pre-processing steps. It is nothing but demand=data["Demand"]
financial=data["Financial"]
mkt_inv=data["Market_inventory"]
dispatch_lt=data["Dispatch_LT"]
packaging_lt=data["Packaging_LT"]
production_lt=data["Production_LT"]
For all the data frames which is present in the dictonary.                                        Also i have validated the value of Dataframe after get_params () it is as it is

@AirSquid  hey i have tried to put all the info. for recreate let me know if the updated code makes sense. Thanks for the support

Use pprint() or model.write to debug the model.
